How to Highlight Search Terms in HTML Ignoring Case and Accents Using JavaScript?
I am working on a scenario where I want to highlight words or parts of words that people search for. I have a function called addMarks that wraps the searched word in the <mark> tag. Of course, this search needs to be case-insensitive, but more than that, it also needs to ignore accents.
Using the function .normalize('NFD').replace(/\p{Diacritic}/gu, ''), I am able to perform searches that ignore accents. However, I am struggling to wrap the searched word in the <mark> tag correctly.
For example, if someone searches for "éner", the highlighting works as expected. But when searching for "ener" (without the accent), the highlighting does not work.
My question: How can I modify the code so that the <mark> tag wraps the search term correctly even when accents are missing ? For instance, if someone searches "ener" instead of "éner", the highlight should still work.
Thanks in advance for your help!
Here also the MRE


    const search = 'éner';

    function escapeRegExp(s) {
        return s.replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, '\\$&');
    }

    function addMarks(liItem, q) {
        if (liItem.textContent.toLowerCase().normalize('NFD').replace(/\p{Diacritic}/gu, '').includes(q.toLowerCase().normalize('NFD').replace(/\p{Diacritic}/gu, ''))) {
            liItem.innerHTML = liItem.innerHTML.replace(
                new RegExp(
                    `(>[^<>]*)(${escapeRegExp(q)})([^<>]*<)`,
                    'gi',
                ),
                '$1<mark>$2</mark>$3',
            );
        }
    }

    for (const liItem of document.querySelectorAll('li')) {
        addMarks(liItem, search);
    }
<ul>
    <li>
        <article>
            <h2>Mot avec accent : <b>énergie</b></h2>
            <p>L'importance de l'<dfn>énergie</dfn> renouvelable ne cesse de croître dans le monde moderne.</p>
        </article>
    </li>
    <li>
        <article>
            <h2>Expression avec caractères spéciaux : <b>Ça va ?</b></h2>
            <p>En français, <dfn>ça va ?</dfn> est une façon courante de demander des nouvelles.</p>
        </article>
    </li>
    <li>
        <article>
            <h2>Proverbe français : <b>À cœur vaillant rien d'impossible</b></h2>
            <p>Ce proverbe met en avant la détermination face aux défis :À cœur vaillant rien d'impossible.</p>
        </article>
    </li>
</ul>




Take the search term and  create am array of versions of that search term you need to highlight. Then loop over the array with each iteration wrapping the current iteration search term in <mark> elements.

I am wondering: isn't it a bit redundant to first search for a pattern, and then search and replace that pattern? Not 100% sure of my remark, because maybe that regexp is slow. But I feel that you would be better off, speed wise, to just apply the regexp, which will search for the pattern and replace if needed, in one pass. And here, related to your problem, that would avoid the implicit code duplication, that leads to "matching work works for the if, but not for the replace inside that if" problem of yours).

Because, as I think you have identified already, that is your problem: you correctly finds, despites accents differences, that the 1st li does contain the searched word. But can't do the same thing for the replacement part of the code. So you need to start thinking on how to create a RegEx that matches all combination of "ener", regardless of accent. But by doing so, you are reinventing the same thing you did for the if contains part. And always risk to have some slight behavior difference between the two.

So, in short, I would try to create a regex that allows accent and capitals and then use that regex for both detection of li to be processed, and replacement (possibly, but not necessarily, with the same code)

Another way, if you can assume that words you search are not split by some tags (such as <span>EDF <b>É</b>nergie <b>N</b>ouvelle</span>, is to directly search you words in the innerHTML of each li, once "normalized", with a simple .indexOf (on the normalized version of both the innerHTML and the search term). And then insert some <mark> in the original innerHTML at the same index. But that implies the said asumption, since "ener" is nowhere to be found in <span><b>e</b>ner</span>

range based method
(This was written after the next section, but since it is probably better, I put it first. Still not ideal tho)
If we really want to find text regardless of any HTML formatting, highlight that part of text, even what that means splitting some subtree in halves like this case, and yet not reimplementing a HTML parser, then, no "just search and replace in strings" could work I think.
Think of the case where you want to find l'ener in content L'<b>énergie</b> renouvelable. The <mark> you would need to insert would split <b> in two halves. You would want to end up with <mark>L'<b>éner</b></mark><b>gie</b> renouvelable. That is not a easy task that can be done at string level. There is a duplication of the b tag that can only be done reasoning at DOM tree level.
Fortunately, ranges can do that (extract some parts that may split some subtree in halves, and duplicate them if needed)
Here is an example code that do that


// This is just your code to remove capitals and accent. I just took it as it and put it in a function to shorten usage
function normalize(s){
    return s.toLowerCase().normalize('NFD').replace(/\p{Diacritic}/gu, '');
}

let oldcontent=false;
function go(){
    // Same trick as before: just of the sake of the demo, reset marks each time
    if(oldcontent===false) oldcontent=document.querySelector('ul').innerHTML;
    else document.querySelector('ul').innerHTML=oldcontent;
    let search = normalize(document.querySelector('#searchTerm').value);
    while(window.find('',false,false));
    while(window.find(search, false, true)){
        let r=window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
        let c=r.extractContents();
        let nn=document.createElement('mark');
        nn.appendChild(c);
        r.insertNode(nn);
    }
    let s=window.getSelection();
    if(s) s.removeAllRanges();
}
<input id=searchTerm><button onclick="go();">GO</button>

<ul>
    <li>
        <article>
            <h2>Mot avec accent : <b>énergie</b></h2>
            <p>L'importance de l'<dfn>énergie</dfn> renouvelable ne cesse de croître dans le monde moderne.</p>
        </article>
    </li>
    <li>
        <article>
            <h2>Expression avec caractères spéciaux : <b>Ça va ?</b></h2>
            <p>En français, <dfn>ça va ?</dfn> est une façon courante de demander des nouvelles.</p>
        </article>
    </li>
    <li>
        <article>
            <h2>Proverbe français : <b>À cœur vaillant rien d'impossible</b></h2>
            <p>Ce proverbe met en avant la détermination face aux défis :À cœur vaillant rien d'impossible.</p>
        </article>
    </li>
</ul>



Note that this suffer from one, maybe big, problem: window.find is not standard.
But on another hand, it is not the main trick in this code. The main trick is the extract/insertNodes of range. If we don't have a window.find, then you would need to iterate all possible range another way.
For example, creating a list of textNodes, and then iterates for all textNodes, and for all offset in that textNode for start, likewise for end, to search for when normalize(range.toString()) is what you want.
But at least, the extractContents/insertNode take care of the node duplication (if needed) for you.
Note that, with window.find in reality I don't need the "remove accent / remove capitals" function. It is window.find that search ignoring accents and case.
Without window.find
One example of how it can be done without window.find.
It can most certainly be optimized.
I could for example, once for all, find a start/end that have the needed character, and then, at each step, move both one character, instead of that "move the start if it is too short, move the end otherwise" method.
function nofind(){
    // Reset content for the sake of demo
    let ul=document.querySelector('ul');
    if(oldcontent===false) oldcontent=ul.innerHTML;
    else ul.innerHTML=oldcontent;

    // get the list of textNodes
    let n, textNodes=[], walk=document.createTreeWalker(ul,NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT,null,false);
    while(n=walk.nextNode()) textNodes.push(n);

    // pattern to search
    let search = normalize(document.querySelector('#searchTerm').value);

    // Search backward for text part (backward because I don't want insertion of mark to alter the nodes I intend to continue to visit
    let r = document.createRange();
    let en=textNodes.length-1, eo=textNodes[en].length-1;
    let sn=en, so=eo;
    for(;;){
        r.setStart(textNodes[sn],so);
        try{
            r.setEnd(textNodes[en], eo);
        }catch(e){
            console.log("st", sn, textNodes[sn], so);
            console.log("en", en, textNodes[en], eo);
            break;
        }
        if(r.toString().length<search.length){ // We need to set the start of the renge one char before
            if(so>0){
                so--;
                continue;
            }
            if(sn>0){
                sn--;
                so=textNodes[sn].length-1;
                continue;
            }
            break; // We can't go before, there is nothing before
        }
        if(normalize(r.toString())==search){
            let c=r.extractContents();
            let nn=document.createElement('mark');
            nn.appendChild(c);
            r.insertNode(nn);
            en=sn;
            eo=so;
        }
        // Either way (we found patter or not), we need to move end cursor one step before
        if(eo>0){
            eo--;
            continue;
        }
        if(en>0){
            en--;
            eo=textNodes[en].length-1;
            continue;
        }
        break; // Defensive, should not happen without the other break to happen before
    }
}

indexOf in innerHTML
Just to show what I have in mind in my last comment.
Again not perfect : it makes the asumption that you can find the search term in the innerHTML of your li.
So, as I've mentioned, it wouldn't work for <b>É</b>nergie. More serious problem: what if the user search for the term span or div.
But (I am not 100% sure, tho, since I didn't really try to decode your regex) I feel that you probably have the same kind of problems with your current solution (except that it is less likely, since the term need to be first found in .textContent before the regex is ran. But we could imagine a scenario where the user search for div in a text such as Les solutions diverses au problème de <div>l'Énergie</div>. I, vaguely, feel that you've tried to address that withe your [^<>] and the like in your regex. But trying to reimplement a html parser in a regex never really works: there is always someone to show you a counter example on SO :-D
For example: don't try with b as search term :D
Also, I tried to stick as much as possible to your code. Otherwise, I would suggest to perform, on q/search the toLower/normalize/replace only once for all before calling addMarks


    let search = 'ener';

    function escapeRegExp(s) {
        return s.replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, '\\$&');
    }

    function addMarks(liItem, q) {
        let listd = liItem.innerHTML.toLowerCase().normalize('NFD').replace(/\p{Diacritic}/gu, '');
        let qstd=q.toLowerCase().normalize('NFD').replace(/\p{Diacritic}/gu, '');
        let offset=0;
        for(;;){
            let ix=listd.indexOf(qstd);
            if(ix<0) break;
            liItem.innerHTML = liItem.innerHTML.slice(0,offset+ix) + '<mark>' + liItem.innerHTML.slice(offset+ix, offset+ix+qstd.length) + '</mark>' + liItem.innerHTML.slice(offset+ix+qstd.length);
            offset += ix+qstd.length+13;//13=size of <mark></mark>
            listd = listd.slice(ix+qstd.length);
        }
    }

    let org=false;
    function go(){
        // reset to original value (without marks)
        if(org===false) org=document.querySelector('ul').innerHTML;
        else document.querySelector('ul').innerHTML=org;
        // I think tolower and stuff should be done directly here, but I let it as is
        search = document.querySelector('#searchTerm').value;
        for (const liItem of document.querySelectorAll('li')) {
            addMarks(liItem, search);
        }
    }
<input id=searchTerm></input>
<button id=doSearch onclick="go();">GO</button>
<ul>
    <li>
        <article>
            <h2>Mot avec accent : <b>&eacute;nergie</b></h2>
            <p>L'importance de l'<dfn>énergie</dfn> renouvelable ne cesse de croître dans le monde moderne.</p>
        </article>
    </li>
    <li>
        <article>
            <h2>Expression avec caractères spéciaux : <b>Ça va ?</b></h2>
            <p>En français, <dfn>ça va ?</dfn> est une façon courante de demander des nouvelles.</p>
        </article>
    </li>
    <li>
        <article>
            <h2>Proverbe français : <b>À cœur vaillant rien d'impossible</b></h2>
            <p>Ce proverbe met en avant la détermination face aux défis :À cœur vaillant rien d'impossible.</p>
        </article>
    </li>
</ul>



Note : I added a field for the search term, and a button to do the addMarks, just because I am too lazy to experiment by changing the code each time. And then I figured out that marks are not removed, so I added a reset. That is obviously irrelevant in your real code.

@PeterSeliger Indeed. But nor would anything ressembling the initial solution. Because, well, even assuming that we have an algorithm (for example, something that parses both innerHTML and textContent in parallel, and find ranges in both matching the word) that can tells you exeactly were in the text is the pattern, and where in the HTML it is coded, L'<b>énergie</b> couldn't be marked that easily for search l'ener. Obviously <mark>L'<b>éner</mark>gie</b> doesn't make any sense.

So we would need to find a way to create either 2 marks <mark>L'</mark><b><mark>éner</mark>gie</b>. Or two <b>: <mark>L'<b>éner</b></mark><b>gie</b>. The provided code doesn't go anywhere near doing that (and that is, of course, a simple case. We could, if we want, torture that, and providing examples of a mark that would need traversing partially 5 levels of dom subtrees)

If we don't want to end up writing some HTML parser to deal with such case, one way could be to play with some Range (extractContent, insertNodes, ...).
